# India Post API - How to extract all pin codes from https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/api

Tags: api, post

I just want to extract all pin codes from this url :https://data.gov.in/resources/all-india-pincode-directory/api Any help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet solved this, you can try the [R](https://github.com/econabhishek/datagovindia) package (or [python](https://pypi.org/project/datagovindia/) depending upon your coding environment) - datagovindia.

First, get an API key from the platform by creating an account on it. Here is a [guide](https://data.gov.in/help/how-use-datasets-apis) to get you started.

The first thing you have to note is the "index name" or resource id. For this API it is **6176ee09-3d56-4a3b-8115-21841576b2f6**

Here's the R code:

```
#install.packages("datagovindia")    
library(datagovindia)

#Validate your API , replace xxx your API key
register_api_key("xxx")

#get data
pincode_data<-get_api_data(api_index = "6176ee09-3d56-4a3b-8115-21841576b2f6")

#You are done! Preview it : 
head(pincode_data)

     officename pincode officetype deliverystatus  divisionname  regionname  circlename
1   Chakragaon S.O  744112        S.O       Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
2      Chatham S.O  744102        S.O   Non-Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
3    Delanipur S.O  744102        S.O   Non-Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
4 Marine Jetty S.O  744101        S.O   Non-Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
5   Minnie Bay S.O  744103        S.O   Non-Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
6 N.S.Building S.O  744101        S.O   Non-Delivery A - N Islands Calcutta HQ West Bengal
      taluk  districtname                 statename
1 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
2 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
3 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
4 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
5 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
6 Portblair South Andaman ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
```

You can find more guides on the repo.